# Django: Make items in ManyToMany field unavailable once it is "used"?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

**if this is my models.py:**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name            

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "%s" % self.slug 


class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)     

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name            

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "%s" % self.slug
```

My desired functionality is to have any *Category* that has already had a an *Item* assigned to it to not be available for any other *Items*. For example, if I have these *Categories*: { Animal, Vegetable, Mineral }, and i assign the *Item* "Rock" to the *Category* "Mineral", when I add the next *Item*, "Mineral" will be unavailable from the list in admin. Hopefully that makes sense, and thank you for your time.

Comment: I guess what I'm looking for is a way to (maybe in admin.py) to check the list of Categories, and only populate the ManyToMany field with Categories that do not have an "Item" assigned to them.

Answer (score 0):

You could specify an "available" field, something like this. And then just show "availables" to the user.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name            

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "%s" % self.slug 

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None):
        if self.item_set.all():
            self.available = False
        super(Category, self).save()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I need it "automated".

Answer (score 0):

If you only want each Category to be associated with a single Item, then you haven't got a ManyToMany relationship at all. You should restructure your models to make it a ForeignKey from Category to Item.

Comment: yes, but each Item can have multiple Categories. It's just not okay for each Category to be used more that once by Items. Hope that makes sense.

For example, using the models above, an Item "Horse Sculpture" could be assigned to **both** "Animal" and "Mineral" categories. This would "lock out" those categories, and when adding more Items, "Animal" and "Mineral" would be not be available.

Comment: Exactly. The model where an Item can have multiple Categories, but each Category can only be used once, is a many-to-one - implemented in Django as a ForeignKey.